# How to switch between apps without restarting/refreshing previous app in Swift

Tags: ios, swift

Upon signing up users are asked to confirm their e-mail. When switching between my app and gmail and then return to my app 10 seconds later, the app restarts and does not resume from the last view. How can I prevent this behaviour? By the way I have removed all code from appdelegate and scenedelegate that call for a specific view at launch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you switch from your app to any other app (like Gmail), your app state is going from active to inactive and then eventually to suspended and not running.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/app_and_environment/managing_your_app_s_life_cycle

In general, if you switch to another app, it is not immediately shut down, but you have no guarantee of how long it would be kept in memory. The system is free to decide at any point that it needs more resources and kill your app.

The solution you are looking for is "state restoration." In most basic forms - you can just store data on disk or in user defaults (depending on what it is and if it's private - user defaults are not recommended for PII). When your app starts, you can check what is stored and jump right to that point in the app. There is also an Apple recommended way of state restoration, might work better than writing it manually.

Here you have a couple of useful resources from Apple:

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/view_controllers/preserving_your_app_s_ui_across_launches

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontroller/restoring_your_app_s_state